# Wrong route matched with same sub name

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle, symfony-routing, knpmenu

here is my menu class.

```
public function createShopAdminMenu()
{
    $menu = $this->factory
        ->createItem('root')
        ->setChildrenAttribute('class', 'nav nav-pills')
    ;

    $menu->addChild('Administration', ['route' => 'admin_dashboard', 'extras' => [ 'safe_label' => true ]]);

    $products = $menu
        ->addChild('Products', ['route' => 'shop_admin_product', 'extras' => [ 'safe_label' => true ]])
        ->setDisplayChildren(false)
    ;
    $products->addChild('Create', ['route' => 'shop_admin_product_form']);

    return $menu;
}
```

And this is the template where I'm using the menu.

```
{{ knp_menu_render('shop_admin', { 'allow_safe_labels': true, 'currentClass': 'active', 'ancestorClass': 'active' }) }}
```

This is my routing table (as overview!).

[image: Routes]

And here is the screenshot how it look.

[image]

Then the **bug** */* **problem** with the `sub`route(s).

[image]

You can see... Both are active. That's bad. I dont know why. I think because the voter or something marks the `/admin` as current because the others starts with `/admin`.

Thanks in Advance for ideas!

Comment: You are probably right. I guess, knpmenu believes that Products is a sub-page of Administration because of the routing. A simple fix would be to give your dashboard another route, such as `/admin/dashboard`.